# Assign row names and column names to many matrices

Tags: r

I have a problem which I am sure has an easy answer, but I seem to be unable to figure it out. I have many matrices of the same format, and would like to assign the same column and row names to all of them. I am trying to do this in a loop, by calling all the matrices and then to assign the names.

Here is my reproducible example.

```
mnames <- letters[1:10] # The names to be assigned

mat1 <- matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)
mat2 <- matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)
mat3 <- matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)

obs <- c("mat2", "mat2", "mat3")

for(i in obs){
  rownames(as.name(i)) <- mnames
  colnames(as.name(i)) <- mnames
}
```

It seems like the loop does not call the object, but I do not understand why? Would be grateful for any help, I have tons of matrices and doing all the assigning one by one would be tedious. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `get` the matrix in `for` loop but I think it would be better if you get them in a list with `mget`, change the `dimnames` and then if needed assign it back to global enviroment.

```
list_mat <- lapply(mget(obs), function(x) {dimnames(x) <- list(mnames, mnames);x})
list2env(list_mat, .GlobalEnv)
```